# How to convert normal column as primary key in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column named UserID and table name is Users. I want to make UserID column as primary key . How to make existing column as primary key

getting this error while making pk

Sql query

```
Alter table Users
ADD Primary Key (UserID)
```

error

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key
>   was found for the object name 'dbo.Users' and the index name
>   'pk_UserID'. The duplicate key value is (5).

Comment: check whether column having duplicate entries

Comment: you can't, if the the values in the column are not unique and null

Comment: This is because you have a *"duplicate key"* in the field *"UserID"*

Comment: This is because of the duplicate value in the userid column the value 5 is duplicate in userid column

Comment: @SurajKumar that answer should be a comment. The code is the same as the OP's and the rest is identical to the other comments

Comment: thanks . i had duplicate record 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicated values in the `UserID` field and this can't be used as `PRIMARY KEY` because an index has to be **unique**.

If you want to get the ids that are duplicated, you can use the following query :

```
SELECT UserId AS "Duplicated ids"
FROM Users
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(UserId) > 1;
```

In example :

```
 CREATE TABLE Users
 (
 UserId INT
 );

 INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1), (1), (2), (3), (4), (4), (4), (5), (6), (7), (7);

 SELECT UserId AS "Duplicated ids"
 FROM Users
 GROUP BY UserId
 HAVING COUNT(UserId) > 1;
 GO
```

```
 | Duplicated ids |
 | -------------: |
 |              1 |
 |              4 |
 |              7 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fb2f9fd1cb50f0ad421d8c442fbdc4a)*

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses a `UNIQUE` index to enforce non-duplicate values behind a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint. This is done for performance reasons. The error message says that when trying to build this index, there are duplicate entries for the `UserID` column, so the index can't be created and therefore primary key neither.

You can do 2 things:

- Delete the duplicate UserIDs. First find the duplicate rows with a query like the following. The `RepeatRanking` will show ranks for each set of similar UserID. You can use the 2nd query to delete the ones ranking higher than 1. You can use a column list on the `ORDER BY` to determine the 1st entry of the ranking (the one you are going to keep).

  ```
  -- To query
  SELECT
      U.*,
      RepeatRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY U.UserID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM
      Users AS U
  ORDER BY
      RepeatRanking ASC


  -- To Delete:
  ;WITH UserRowNumbers AS
  (
      SELECT
          U.*,
          RepeatRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY U.UserID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
          Users AS U
  )
  DELETE U FROM
      UserRowNumbers AS U
  WHERE
      U.RepeatRanking > 1
  ```
- Assign new UserIDs to repeated ones (in case you don't want to delete them). For this you want to determine if you want to keep all current users or not, maybe you have repeated UserID but they are actually different users. Assuming the `UserID` is an `INT`, you can use the following query to reassign duplicate UserIDs:

  ```
  DECLARE @MaxUserID INT = (SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM Users WITH(UPDLOCK))

  IF @MaxUserID IS NULL
      SET @MaxUserID = 0

  ;WITH UserRowNumbers AS
  (
      SELECT
          U.*,
          RepeatRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY U.UserID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
          Users AS U
  )
  UPDATE U SET
      UserID = @MaxUserID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM
      UserRowNumbers AS U
  WHERE
      U.RepeatRanking > 1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To set existing column as primary key, run following sql script in the Query window.

```
Alter table Users
ADD Primary Key (UserID)
```

Note the value in table for UserID should not be duplicate one. Here you are getting error because the value in UserId is more than once that value is `5`.